# Rails JavaScript error in production: 'Invalid left-hand side in assignment'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

My Rails 5 app works fine in development, but throws a JS error in production:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

This error does not happen on my development machine, only the production server. The javascript is precompiled to one line in production so I can't see where the issue lies.

I tried running `rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production` on my development machine but it doesn't throw any errors there.

Any clue on how I could try to debug this?

Comment: where does this error appear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

===Updated===

It was bug in [Uglifier](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier) 3.1.0 ([#110](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/issues/110)), the author have released 3.1.1
Just run

```
bundle update
```

to install latest version, and your project should be find in production environment.

===Original Post===

I have same issue too, so checked what I have done recently and successfully narrowed down to a gem: [uglifier](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier).
Seems uglifier 3.1.0 is causing this issue, so I rolled back to 3.0.4

in Gemfile, change following

```
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
```

to:

```
gem 'uglifier', '~> 3.0.4'
```

And it should work.

I have not dig in what's causing this issue...

Comment: Thank you. See my answer above for the github issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. It was with uglifier.

https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/issues/110

Upgrading to 3.1.1 should fix it.